# Is it necessary to use warm_start when tracking oob_score in scikit RandomForestClassifier?

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, scikit-learn

I'm planning on doing feature-selection with `RandomForestClassifier` by using the `feature_importances` and `oob_score`. My plan is to recursively drop the 20% least important features and measure the OOB error until I get a significant drop, as recommended [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68692/feature-selection-with-random-forests).

BUT, I'm baffled by a comment I saw in a scikit [example for tracking oob errors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_ensemble_oob.html). It says: `Setting the warm_start construction parameter to True is necessary for tracking the OOB error trajectory during training.`

Why do they mean by that?? I was planning on using `clone` for each iteration with a new subset of features, and comparing the `oob_score` for each classifier. Am I missing something, or is it just a performance recommendation available in that particular example?

Comment: check the answer of mbq: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41104/number-of-trees-for-random-forest-optimization-using-recursive-feature-eliminati?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I'm a R user but understand the `warm_start` documentation as old trees are saved for later use.

Ideally, when you choose to run a recursive feature selection by a sequence of forests you should pick `warm_start=False`. The idea of a recursive feature selection is that when dropping some features, other features may become more *important* and to 'appreciate' this all trees must be retrained. Depending on your actual implementation, it may defacto be a `cold_start` even if you set `warm_start=True`. Recursive feature selection is for good and bad analogues to backward elimination in regression models.

Remember the internal `OOB_error` cannot be used to decide, when the feature selection should stopped. You will tend to go too far, and the `OOB_error` will be over-optimistic. Use a outer cross-validation to test if you really achieve a increase in prediction performance.

[In the example of tracking oob errors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_ensemble_oob.html) it was stated that `warm_start` is necessary. I would add: ... *"to perform a online monitoring of `OOB_error`as function of added to trees to the ensemble with this very particular wrapper implementation"*.
Just disregard it, it does need to apply to your case. I would just run the feature selection process obviously too far and go drink coffee or hang out in this forum. Later I plot the outcome versus iterations and decide for when it probably would have been a good time to stop.

Comment: I may soon update my opinion on feature selection, see comments:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200823/does-it-makes-sense-to-use-feature-selection-before-random-forest/200959#200959